# What is "soured aesthetic“?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, metaphors

I read the line from this article. https://www.frameawards.com/project/3004210-wemarket

Can someone explain what does "common soured aesthetic" mean in the last paragraph? and, "This buzz associated with a dense trading....", what does the "buzz" refers to?
Many thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided any information in your question. Do not expect people to *have* to follow a link in order to understand what you're asking. Provide an actual quotation of the relevant passage in the question itself.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportaMonica It’s the guy’s third post ever and anywhere, give him some kindness!

Answer (score 1):

#### "Soured" is a typo.

The original paragraph:

> Material choices take into consideration the temperate nature of the space with a **ready- made or common soured** aesthetic with the potential refit only one season away. Along with the paired back structures and material simplicity the sense of a warehouse / commune / traditional market feel is imparted on customers. This buzz associated with a dense trading environment supplemented because of the potential for Ad-hoc / organic planning permutations.

We can see that "common soured" is more or less synonymous with "ready-made", which is a [style of art initiated by Duchamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readymades_of_Marcel_Duchamp) that takes materials that already exist and casts them as art. Readymade can be read as "already made" – nothing was made custom for the space.

With this context clue we can interpret "common soured" to be a typo of "common *sourced*".

Comment: I got it now, Thank you very much for your reply :D

Comment: Though it should be noted that "soured aesthetic" would be a legitimate term of artistic criticism.

Comment: Perhaps after encountering too much Readymades-inspired art @HotLicks